# Is the accuracy equal if the true positive and false positive rates are equal between two groups?

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, binary-data, predictor, accuracy

I was reading the paper "Equality of Opportunity in Supervised Learning" ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02413)).

In that paper there is a feature $A \in \{0,1\}$ and a binary outcome $y \in \{0,1\}$. The population is divided into two sub-populations according to $A$.

Then there is a constraint on the predictor.

In the paper there is written "For the outcome y = 1, the constraint requires that $\hat{Y}$ has equal true positive rates across the two demographics A=0 and A=1."

I translated it into:

$\dfrac{TP_1}{TP_1+FN_1} = \dfrac{TP_2}{TP_2+FN_2},$

where the subscripts indicate the demographics, 1 for $A=0$ and 2 for $A=1$.

In the paper there is also written "for $y$=0, the constraint equalizes the false positive rates," which I translated into:

$\dfrac{FP_1}{TN_1+FP_1} = \dfrac{FP_2}{TN_2+FP_2}.$

So far so good. 
Then the paper says "equalized odds enforces that the accuracy is equally high in all demographics."

The accuracy is defined as the percentage of correct predictions:

$\text{accuracy} = \dfrac{TP+TN}{TP+TN+FP+FN}.$

I am not understanding how to get equal accuracy from the above equations?
If the true positive rates and the false positive rates across the predictions across two subpopulations are equal, is the accuracy across these two subpopulations equal too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the article replied to me as follows:

> Equalized odds implies that FP, FN (and hence also TP and TN) are the
>   same in all groups. Since accuracy is a function of these four
>   numbers, it must also be the same in all groups. You might find this
>   resource helpful in learning more: https://fairmlbook.org/

Answer (score 1):

There must be something wrong with either the reasoning in the paper or your (and my) understanding of their claims.

Here is a small counter example in R:

```
TP1 <- 100
TP2 <- 1
P1 <- 1500
P2 <- 15

FP1 <- 1
FP2 <- 50
N1 <- 4
N2 <- 200

TN1 <- N1 - FP1
TN2 <- N2 - FP2

TPR2 <- TP2/P2
TPR1 <- TP1/P1

FPR2 <- FP2/N2
FPR1 <- FP1/N1

acc2 <- (TP2 + TN2)/(P2+N2)
acc1 <- (TP1 + TN1)/(P1+N1)

TPR2 == TPR1
FPR2 == FPR1
acc2 == acc1
```

This gives:

```
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
```

So accuracy is not equal between groups. But maybe "equally high" should be interpreted as "of comparable value". But even this is questionable, since `acc1=0.07` and `acc2=0.7` in my example.